# How to get superclass' instance of object

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a project and I would like to get the superclass' instance of a certain object at **runtime**, for development purposes.
For example, if I have this method in a class called **SomeClass**:

```
+(id)generateSuperclassInstanceOfObject:(id)object {
    if (object) {
        NSLog(@"The class of the object is %@", [object class])
        Class klass = [object superclass];
        if (!klass)
            NSLog(@"Klass not available");
        else {
            //NSLog(@"The superclass of the object is %@", NSStringFromClass(klass));
            id superObject = (klass *)object;
            //NSLog(@"Correctly generated the superclass instance!");
            return superObject;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And, if I have:

```
@interface A : NSObject
...
@end

@interface B : A
...
@end

@interface C : B
...
@end
```

I would like to do something similar, if it has at least 2 superclasses (as in my case):

```
C *object = [[C alloc] init];

id superInstance = [SomeClass generateSuperclassInstanceOfObject:object];
NSLog(@"Generated correct superInstance of class: %@", [superInstance class]);

id superSuperInstance = [SomeClass generateSuperclassInstanceOfObject:superInstance];
NSLog(@"Generated correct superInstance of class: %@", [superSuperInstance class]);
```

Where NSLog prints:

```
The class of the object is C
Generated correct superInstance of class: B
The class of the object is B
Generated correct superInstance of class: A
```

In my code, it looks

> id superObject = (klass *)object;

is not correct because **klass** is not a type.. I need something that allows me to cast an object in this particular situation, using a "cast generated at runtime", because I don't know from the beginning the hierarchy of the object.

The most important part is that: I know "super" exists, **but I need to create a new object deleting any reference to its subclass**. This must be valid for any object having at least 2 superclasses (so in my case, I shouldn't be able to use the generateSuperclassInstanceOfObject method with argument superSuperInstance, because it has NSObject as superclass).

Any help please?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow. You can cast an object to an instance of its parent, but that doesn't change what it is, just how it's seen. It's possible to take an unknown object and through a lots of runtime tricky deduce it's super type and create one. But it's a new object. Not the object. And you'll need to really know what you are doing to try it. Perhaps if you tell us what you are trying to achieve and why, then we can better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot do what you are trying to do. An object is an instance of a particular class and that never changes.

When an reference to an object of one class is cast to be a reference to an object of a different class the reference object is not changed in anyway, what changes is how the compiler treats the reference.

From your question it is not clear for what purpose you wish to do this. If your intent is to call methods that are inaccessible because they are overridden then the `super` mechanism exists for that purpose.

If this answer doesn't answer your question you can ask a new question, or edit the current one, detailing the *purpose* of what you are trying to do, what you have tried, etc. and someone will probably help you along. (I.e. don't try to expand this question in comments.)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Casting one object as another doesn't change the underlying object at all. So this doesn't change anything.

`id superObject = (klass *)object;`

If you want an instance of the super object then you need to alloc/init it like any other object.

`id superObject = [[klass alloc] init];`

Not sure why you want to do this though... but that is your answer.